# register users through iphone application

Tags: iphone, registration

What are the techniques to register users through the iPhone application? I'd like them to register on my site like many other do, but how to do it from within the application and is it acceptable to do it as the first thing and the user opens the application like desktop application do (EULA and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register users through your iPhone app, you would have to create a form for the user to fill in. The contents of the filled in form should then be sent to your website, which registers the user. There are various ways to send the form data to your website, but I can give you a simple example of how you can do it:

Make a new URL on your website, for example: www.example.com/register-user

From your iPhone app, do a POST to that URL with all the filled in form data as post parameters. Now you can write some server side code that actually registers the user and maybe sends back the result in the response body to the iPhone (as XML or JSON or whatever)